# python dynamic multiple inheritance __init__

Tags: python, class, multiple-inheritance

I am trying to write a plugin environment where I need to do multiple inheritances on an unknown number of classes.  Therefore, I have opted to use the type class creation:

```
class A(object):
   def __init__(self,s):
      self.a="a"
   def testA(self,x):
      print(x)

class B(object):
   def __init__(self,s):
      self.b="b"
   def testA(self,x):
      print(x)

C = type('C', (A,B), {})

x= C("test")
print x.b
```

When I run the above code, I get the error:

```
AttributeError: 'C' object has no attribute 'b'
```

This is because only the **init** for class A is being run when the instance for class C is initialized.  My question is how can I get the class C to have both the **init** for class A as well as the **init** for class B to run when an instance of class C is initialized.  I do realize that if I had class C like the following it would work:

```
class C(A,B):
    def __init__(self,s):
       A.__init__(self,s)
       B.__init__(self,s)
```

However, given that I need to have a dynamic list of classes inherited this will not work.

Comment: Use `super()`, which is intended for exactly this scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you're using python 2 so I'm using this old python 2 `super()` syntax where you have to specify the class and the instance, although it would work in python 3 as well. In python 3 you could also use the shorter `super()` form without parameters.

For multiple inheritance to work is important that the grandparent class `__init__` signature matches the signature of all siblings for that method. To do that, define a common parent class (`MyParent` in this example) whose `__init__` has the same parameter list as all the childs. It will take care of calling the `object`'s `__init__` that doesn't take any parameter, for us.

```
from __future__ import print_function

class MyParent(object):
    def __init__(self, s):
        super(MyParent, self).__init__()

class A(MyParent):
    def __init__(self, s):
        self.a = "a"
        super(A, self).__init__(s)
    def testA(self, x):
        print(x)

class B(MyParent):
    def __init__(self, s):
        self.b = "b"
        super(B, self).__init__(s)

    def testA(self,x):
        print(x)

C = type('C', (A, B), {})

x = C("test")
print(x.b)
```

You can define as many children to `MyParent` as you want, and then all `__init__` methods will be called, provided you used `super()` correctly.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  Could you tell my why there is a super in the init of MyParent?

Comment: it calls `object.__init__`... which does nothing, but you shouldn't rely on it doing nothing. It is the initialization of the parent class, so you should always call it